# Wrong pointer passed to callback through g_source_set_callback()

Tags: c, glib

I'm trying to set up a GLib main loop source to monitor a UDP socket.
However, when the callback for this source is executed, it triggers a segmentation fault. Debugging with GDB reveals that the wrong pointer address is passed to the callback.

```c
GSource *SAPSocketMonitoring =
    g_socket_create_source(SAPSocket, G_IO_IN | G_IO_PRI, NULL);

g_source_attach(SAPSocketMonitoring, NULL);

data_insertIncomingSAPPackets SocketMonitoringData;

SocketMonitoringData.DiscoveryLoop = SAPDiscoveryLoop;
SocketMonitoringData.Database = SDPDatabase;
SocketMonitoringData.Socket = SAPSocket;

g_source_set_callback
(
    SAPSocketMonitoring,
    callback_insertIncomingSAPPackets,
    &SocketMonitoringData,
    NULL
);

g_main_loop_run(SAPDiscoveryLoop);
```

I expect the pointer to `SocketMonitoringData` to be passed to the callback function `callback_insertIncomingSAPPackets`, but here is what GDB tells me :

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdff8) at SAP_discovery.c:85
85      g_main_loop_run(SAPDiscoveryLoop);
(gdb) print SocketMonitoringData 
$2 = {DiscoveryLoop = 0x555555766930, Socket = 0x555555767130 [GSocket], 
  Database = 0x555555769008}
(gdb) print &SocketMonitoringData 
$3 = (data_insertIncomingSAPPackets *) 0x7fffffffdea0
(gdb) s
Removed old entries


Breakpoint 2, callback_insertIncomingSAPPackets (Data=0x555555767130) at ../../headers/lanio.c:544
544     gchar SAPPacketBuffer[SAP_PACKET_BUFFER_SIZE] = {'\0'};
(gdb) q
```

The address passed to `callback_insertIncomingSAPPackets`, instead of `0x7fffffffdea0`, is `0x555555767130`, which is the pointer stored in `SocketMonitoringData.Socket`.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found the answer. I'm going to post it here, since I find that GLib's documentation is a bit obscure on this :

The callback I'm attaching with `g_source_set_callback()` needs to be of type `GSourceFunc`, according to [this](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-set-callback). A callback of this type takes as parameters only one pointer to the user data, according to [this](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GSourceFunc).

*However*, I am creating the socket source using `g_socket_create_source()`, to which the attached callback must be of `GSocketSourceFunc` type, according to [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSocket.html#g-socket-create-source). And a callback of type `GSocketSourceFunc` must have 3 arguments, according to [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSocket.html#GSocketSourceFunc)... The first one being the pointer to the `GSocket`, which is what was driving me crazy.

I don't understand why the compiler did not trigger an error... If someone can explain it to me it would be great.

Comment: It's hard to say why you didn't get a compiler warning without seeing the rest of your code, but maybe you had function pointer cast warnings turned off?